# Uploading static images in Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to upload JPEG images to my Google App Engine website; these images will then be referenced within HTML pages of my website.
I've placed my images in a directory /img in the root directory of my GAE project and configured by app.yaml file according to the official docs (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles) as follows:

```
handlers:
- url: /img
  static_dir: img

- url: /javascript
  static_dir: javascript

- url: /.*
  script: main.application
```

However, every time I try to access an image at mywebsite.appspot.com/img/testImg.jpg, I get a 404 Failed to Load Resource error -- even though I have a testImg.jpg file in my /img directory. 
I placed a dummy text file in my /img directory and could successfully retrieve and display mywebsite.appspot.com/img/test.txt, so I'm not sure why my images are uploading. I've looked over the Google App Engine guide many times and can't find any answers... my app.yaml file looks exactly like what their example has.

Comment: Do you have a `skip_files` entry at all?

Comment: Urls are case sensitive, so make sure you use the proper spelling testImg.jpg in all places.  When you say the img directory is at the root level, you mean at the same level as app.yaml, right?  By chance, are you using Push To Deploy?  If so, try deploying from command line or GAELauncher.  PTD has static files bug.

Comment: did you make a recent change in the version number and forgot to set it as the new default? Do that only happen to an image, or any new files added (e.g. html) are also 404?

Comment: I ended up converting the files to .png files and everything is working now (literally exactly the same setup as before, but the images are now .png and the url's reference img.png)

I didn't have a skip_files and I was deploying from command line. What I did notice is that windows 8.1 seemed to be naming all my .jpg images as .JPG (capitalized) and there wasn't a way for me to make .JPG lowercase. I wasn't sure if the case mattered, so I just switched to a different format.